# Sumlist and appending problems

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that takes in four numbers they can be **negative or positive** and it should sum all the numbers together and then print the **sum**.

My problem comes with the **append** line, I am trying to place it inside the list but it keeps coming up with an error and I am unsure why.

Here is the Code:

```
def sumList(NumList, list):
    sum = 0
    for num in list:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum

NumList = []

while (True):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    if (number != 0):
        number.append(number, NumList) #Here keeps coming up as an error

    else:
        sumList()
        break

print(NumList)
```

Thank you for having the time to read this.

Comment: The syntax for append would be `NumList.append(number)` which would append `number` onto the end of `NumList`. There are number of other issues with the code that will prevent it from running how you want (e.g. you aren't passing `NumList` to `sumList`, you aren't accepting the returned value from `sumList`, `sumList` should only need the one list parameter).

Comment: Please do not use built-in names as variables. Also, you might want to re-structure your code entirely (e.g. read a basic tutorial on how to declare and use functions properly, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, your code is a mess. This works:

```py
numlist = []

number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
while number != 0:
    numlist.append(number)
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))

print(sum(numlist))
```

To sum the values of an iterable, you can simply use the builtin `sum` function. And to append something to a list, use `list.append(value)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `NumList.append(number)` or `NumList.extend(number)`

code snippet:

```
def sumList(NumList, list):
    sum = 0
    for num in list:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum

NumList = []

while (True):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    if (number != 0):
        NumList.append(number) #correct this

    else:
        sumList()
        break

print(NumList)
```